# Can the size of an std::array be automatically derived when used as a non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, non-type

The following works. However, is it possible to omit the SIZE template parameter (i.e. not necessarily the SIZE template argument to array)?

```
template <
    class T,
    size_t SIZE,
    std::array<T, SIZE> & ARR
>
class Foo{};
```

In other words, is it possible for the compiler to deduce SIZE from the array template argument? Thus obviating the line

```
const size_t SIZE,
```

Comment: Do you really need `SIZE` as a member, can't you just use `ARR.size()`?

Comment: AFAICT I need it to satisfy the SIZE param in the array param

Comment: This code won't compile. One for the missing semicolon and another for the fact that you can't use a class as a non-type template parameter.

Comment: I forgot the reference when I minified. It should work now as long as any clients pass an array with external linkage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using C++17 you can with auto template parameters:

```
template<auto&>
struct Foo {};
```

You can then send a reference to a global:

```
void test() {
    static auto arr = std::array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // no linkage works in C++17
    Foo<arr> f{};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the size at compile-time via [`std::tuple_size(std::array)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_size) (since C++11), e.g.

```
template <
    class ARRAY
>
struct Foo{
    static constexpr size_t SIZE = std::tuple_size<ARRAY>::value;
    using T = typename ARRAY::value_type;
};
```

and use it as

```
Foo<array<int, 3>> f;
```